# Выборка значений родительской категории, если категория пуста в PG

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, выборка

проблема следующая:
Имеется json массив товаров, в которых указывается categoryid. И json массив категорий с ключом categoryid.
При нажатии на категорию, создается запрос на api, с поиском товаров с categoryid и последующий вывод, но это работает для конечных дочерних элементов. Если же нажать на категорию в целом, отображения не будет, по той причине, что в БД товаров напрямую добавленных в  родительскую категорию - нет. Вопрос, есть ли возможность вывода всех дочерних элементов с категориями внутри, если родитель пуст?

```
{
   "categoryid":33, --- Данные не найдутся
   "parentid":0,
   "name":"Комплектующие для компьютеров",
   "leaf":false,
   "url_name":"Komplektujuschie dlja komp'juterov",
   "childrens":[
      {
         "id":240, --- Данные не найдутся
         "leaf":false,
         "name":"Блоки питания",
         "parentId":33,
         "childrens":[
            {
               "id":245, --- Данные найдутся
               "leaf":true,
               "name":"до 500 ватт включительно",
               "parentId":240
            },
            {
               "id":246, --- Данные найдутся
               "leaf":true,
               "name":"до 400 ватт включительно",
               "parentId":240
            },
            {
               "id":247, --- Данные найдутся
               "leaf":true,
               "name":"до 600 ватт включительно",
               "parentId":240
            },
            {
               "id":248, --- Данные найдутся
               "leaf":true,
               "name":"до 800 ватт включительно",
               "parentId":240
            },
            {
               "id":249, --- Данные найдутся
               "leaf":true,
               "name":"свыше 800 ватт",
               "parentId":240
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

[image: Категории]
[image: Товары]

Comment: *есть ли возможность вывода всех дочерних элементов с категориями внутри, если родитель пуст?* Ну есть...

Comment: Имеется в виду товаров.

Answer (score 0):

Приведение выгрузки в подобный вид: [image: Таблица категорий]

А также правильно подобранный запрос, помог решить проблемы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]